# Android notification via Notification hub "The Push Notification System handle for the registration is invalid"

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am rewriting an app from Xamarin to Flutter, I have been struggling with push notification for some time now.

I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-flutter

I have implemented everything for Android and the cross platform code. Not yet started with IOS. The backend and notification hub is up and running for the Xamarin project, which I know is working.

When I register the device I get a 200 and it seems to be working. When I run a test push in Notification hub I get this:
[Image of error code in Notification hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok1yJ.png)

When I try to send one more push I get nothing until I deregister and register again and I will get the error again.

When registering I use push channel, deviceId, platform, and a tag.
I have added the google-services.json file in the app folder of the android project.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to check if the notification hub is configured correctly and tags or tag expressions are used correctly. Also, registration needs to be re-register everytime your app start-up.

You may refer to this article for troubleshoot: [Diagnose dropped notifications in Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer#invalid-registrations)